# Move to specific line and column in one command

Tags: ideavim

Let's say we have a text file that is very long and has many lines. I want to move to 30th line and 15th column in this file.
Are there any VIM commands that could be used to move to mentioned line number and column in one command? Thanks.

Please, do not suggest to use smt like `:30` command and after `15|` this is **NOT** an option.
May VIM has an option to input smt like: `:30,15`, just in another syntax?

The only option I found is to use `:call cursor(30,15)` but it looks little bit too long, as I need to type it each time I want to jump to the another position.

Comment: I suggest you ask this queston on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @January thanks for suggestion. I will create the similar question there as well, in 40 minutes. As it looks like, all *Overflow sites have one posting timer.

Comment: What's wrong with Normal mode (no command line) commands? `30G15|`

Comment: @phd: I assumed OP wanted it for a script or similar

Comment: @January For script the best solution is `:call cursor(30,15)` and the 2nd best `:normal 30G15|`

Comment: @January: "as I need to type it each time I want to jump to the another position"

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own [command-line command](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:command). Define it in `~/.vimrc` and it will be available everywhere. Define:

```
:command -nargs=* Go call cursor(<f-args>)
```

Run:

```
:Go 30 15
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like an option for terminal VIM. By default, I use IntelliJ IDEA VIM plugin, looks like `:call cursor` doesn't support by plugin. No way.

Comment: Note that IdeaVim is not Vim. You should always mention it If you actually want a solution for a specific Vim imitation.

Comment: Sorry for that inconsistency. My bad. Anyway, I have tested all purposed solutions in vim from terminal first. Thanks.
I will be glad if somebody will suggest workaround for IntelliJ VIM emulator as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want to move across two dimensions but Vim commands are limited to one dimension, therefore you can't move to line 30 *and* column 15 with a single built-in command.

Here are the shortest key sequences to move to column 15 of line 30:

```
" in normal mode
30G15|

" in command-line mode and normal mode
:30<CR>15|<CR>

" in command-line mode
:30norm15|<CR>

" from the shell
$ vim foo.txt +norm30G15\|<CR>
```

Note that the first suggestion above is already the shortest theoretically possible sequence because you would need:

1. at least one key for the command itself,
2. at least one key to separate the two coordinates,
3. the vertical coordinate (can't be shortened),
4. and the horizontal coordinate (can't be shortened).

The only improvement I can think of to `30G15|` would be to use keys that don't require a modifier but, frankly, I am not sure that it is worth the hassle.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that is an only way. However, I thought VIM has everything =) I'm wondering if by any chance it has smth, I have asked.